# div ignoring height with background image

Tags: html, css, background

I have a problem with my div's not responding as I think they should. I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agj2umw9/) to make it easier to follow.

Now here is the html markup:

```
<div class="img-hack">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/250/" class="img-top" />
    <div class="left-bg"></div>
    <div class="right-bg"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the corresponding css:

```
.img-hack {
    display:block;
    height:250px;
}
.img-top {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.left-bg {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/20/250/");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.right-bg {
    background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/20x250/8f388f/fff");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

To my understanding the parent from right-bg and left-bg is img-hack. So setting height to 100% should make them same size. **But** it is not. Both divs are expanding down to the very end of the page (see the Fiddle: the bg-images are stopping but the divs (blue and red) are expanding down to the very end)

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `.left-bg`/`.right-bg` elements are absolutely positioned. Thus, they are removed from the normal flow and they don't take their parent into consideration.

In your case, all you need to do is relatively position the parent element `.img-hack`.

In doing so, the absolutely positioned children elements are positioned *relative* to the parent, they therefore take its height.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kos1rxgu/)

```
.img-hack {
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`absolute` messes your page up: Were you going for something like this?

```
<div class="img-hack">
<div class="left-bg"></div>
<div class="right-bg"></div>
<div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/250/" class="img-top" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-hack {
    display:block;
    height:250px;
    background-color: lime;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.imagewrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.img-top {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.left-bg {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/20/250/");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
.right-bg {
    background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/20x250/8f388f/fff");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    float:right;
}
```